# Transform centimeters to inches only for certain values in a column in Python

Tags: python

I have a dataframe with 2 columns. In one it has values type float ( 44.00, 45.00 like this) and in the other has measure ( inches , centimeters etc). I want to transform all values to inches.

I try to write a function :

```
def inches_to_cm (column):
    for i in range(df['Item_lenght']):
        if df['lenght_measure']=='centimeters': 
            i = i/2.54 
        return i
```

But when I am trying to apply it like this :

```
inches_to_cm(df['Item_lenght'])
```

I am getting this error TypeError: 'Series' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Any ideas how can I apply it?

Thanks

Comment: I think there is a error in this line for i in range(df['Item_lenght']): because df['Item_lenght'] is a series but range function is python requires a integer as a parameter

Comment: If I try: def inches_to_cm (column):
    for i in df['Item_lenght']:
        if df['lenght_measure']=='centimeters': 
            i = i/2.54 
        return i           then I am getting this error when I try to apply it : ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Answer (score 0):

It is best not to manually iterate over pandas dataframes.
Try something like this:

```
df.loc[df["lenght_measure"]=="centimeters", "Item_lenght"] = df[df["lenght_measure"]=="centimeters"]["Item_lenght"]/2.54
```

Explanation:
Left hand side: loc is used to access a group of rows and columns. We access the group where "length_measure" is in centimeters and we select the "item_length" column.

Right hand side: we select the whole dataframe where "lenght_measure" is equal to centimeters. Then we select the "item_length" column and divide it by 2.54.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the code and explanation. Now I am getting this error : TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'float'

Comment: @AnamariaSitaru are you sure your item_length column is a float column? If not convert the column to floats.

Comment: @aerobe you were right. It's working now.